# My CSS does not appear when I use "extend" and "block" in Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have spent half a day trying to figure this out. I ended up passing the CSS through the HTML style attribute. What have I done and tried:

1. In **settings.py** I have included:

```
   django.contrib.staticfiles
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

2. In **layout.html**:

```
   {% load static %}
   <link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

3. The static files folders are organized the following:

> **app_name/static/auctions/styles.css**
> 4. And extending the layout and filling the body block

- I have tried adding `{% load static %}` on top;
- I have put `<link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">` afterwards and restarted the server, yet all this to no avail;
  Template:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %} 
{% load humanize %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}

    {% if listing.closed == True %}
        <div style="background-color: whitesmoke; height: 110%; width: 100%; position: absolute; opacity: 0.6; z-index: 2;">
            <div style="margin-top: 30%; font-size: xxx-large;">
                <center>
                    <strong>
                        This listing is closed. <br>
                        <p style="color: green;">{% if request.user == winner.user %} You ({{ winner.user }}) have Won the auction! Congrats! {% endif %}</p>
                    </strong>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if error_check == True %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <center>
                Your bid is lower than the current bid! Try with a higher one.
            </center>
        </div>
    {% elif error_check == False %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <center>
                Your bid was successfully placed!
            </center>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div>
        <div>
            {% if button %}
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'view_list' listing.id %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="close_list" value="True">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Close the Auction">
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {% if not watchlisted or watchlisted.watchlist == False %}
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'view_list' listing.id %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="watchlist_add" value="True">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to Watchlist">
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'view_list' listing.id %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="watchlist_add" value="False">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove from Watchlist">
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <h3>Listing: {{ listing.title }}</h3>
        <img src="{{ listing.image }}" alt="Listings' Images">
        <p>{{ listing.description }}</p>
        {% if not bid %}
            <strong>${{ listing.price|stringformat:"1.2f" }}</strong>
        {% else %}
            <strong>${{ bid|stringformat:"1.2f" }}</strong>
        {% endif %}
        
        <p> {{ total_bids }} bid(s) so far. {% if bid_user %} {{ bid_user }} {% endif %}</p>
        <form method="POST" name="bidding" action="{% url 'view_list' listing.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>   
                <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0 2px; height: 6px; z-index: 1;">
                    {% crispy form %}
                </div>   
                <div class="input-group-append" >
                    <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Bid">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div style="width: 222;">
            <form action="{% url 'view_list' listing.id %}" name="comment" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" value="Comment">
                {% crispy comment %}
                
            </form>
            <div>
                {% for c in comments %}
                    <ul>{{ c.user }}: {{ c.comment }} {{c.created_at}}</ul> 
                {% empty %}
                    No comments yet.
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <h4>Details</h4>
            <li>Listed by: {{ listing.user }} </li>
            <li>Category: {{ listing.category }} </li>
            <li>Listing created at: {{ listing.created_at }} </li>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you probably override head block of layout.html which contains your css declaration

Comment: If you're running with `DEBUG = False` then `collectstatic` needs to be run. Probably not your issue, but worth mentioning just in case :)

Comment: I haven't set a `STATIC_ROOT` and ran `collectstatic` and yet I don't understand why should I, since this is recommended for development environment..?

Comment: If you're in dev with `DEBUG=True` then `collectstatic` is not needed, no. Just wanted to check that wasn't the issue though :)

Comment: BTW, your folder structure is mildly confusing - does `MY_APP` refer to the root django project folder, or the current app? Within the apps you should structure as `app_name/static/app_name/<files>` and then access as `{% static 'app_name/<file>' %}`

Comment: It is as you say I've edited the post.

Comment: @AlexeyPopov What do you mean by that? I am beginner and I didn't understand you clearly.

Comment: @LBD_23 show template which extends layout.html

Comment: @AlexeyPopov I have edited it, can you try to help me. Where should I've put the `{% load static}` and is there anything else missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the browser and particularly with the **cache**...

Answer (score 0):

in your main_urls ensure to  include the following

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static,staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

this tell points django to look for static file in a given url for static